# ReactJS pass function as a property to onStatusChange

Tags: reactjs

Why the `"this"` in `this.props.onStatusChange(taskstatus)`; is `TypeError: this.props.onStatusChange is not a function`? How to bind it correctly?

Dashboard component

```
export default function Dashboard() {

  const handleStatusChange = (params) => {
    if(params==='success')
      setIsLoading(false)
    else
      setIsLoading(true)
  };

  const uuid = "";

 <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
                  <Guest onStausChange={this.handleStatusChange.bind(this)} uuid={uuid}/>
                </TabPanel>
```

Guest component:

```
class Guest extends React.Component {

 loadData = async (uuid) => {
    const taskstatus = await this.apiClient.checkStatus(uuid);
    console.log(taskstatus);
    this.props.onStatusChange(taskstatus);
    if (taskstatus === 'success') {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);

      //Inform parent component about status change 
      //Pass all required details from Guest to parent component here
      this.setState({ finished: true });
      this.props.onStatusChange(taskstatus);

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to use `this` in function component. use it directly like below:

```
<Guest onStausChange={handleStatusChange} uuid={uuid}/>
```

`edited:`
I also think you need to add `super(props)` to your `Guest` component becuase you're using `this.props` in that component:

```
class Guest extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
   super(props)
 }

 loadData = async (uuid) => {
    const taskstatus = await this.apiClient.checkStatus(uuid);
    console.log(taskstatus);
    this.props.onStatusChange(taskstatus);
    if (taskstatus === 'success') {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);

      //Inform parent component about status change 
      //Pass all required details from Guest to parent component here
      this.setState({ finished: true });
      this.props.onStatusChange(taskstatus);

    }
  }
```

Comment: Somehow I get this error in Guest "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.props.onStatusChange is not a function"

Comment: @dev did you try the solution?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I have already super(props) in constructor. Still the same error. Maybe there is something wrong with const handleStatusChange in Dashboard component. Any other ideas?

Comment: Had a typo with onStausChange instead of onStatusChange

Answer (score 0):

No need to bind in React hook Use simple like this in render

```
<Guest onStausChange={handleStatusChange} uuid={uuid}/>
```

Comment: Somehow I get this error in Guest "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.props.onStatusChange is not a function"

Comment: This error may arries do to class and functional component combination.. to reduce this error convert your 'Guest' Class also in functional component. Hook can be added as Child to Class component but you face error while adding Class Component as child of Hook Component